# bash multiline regex capturing groups

Tags: regex, bash

I have ([tested](https://regex101.com/r/O0tyYf/1/) ) regex:

```
(?m)^[ ]{0,}<(?<tag>.*?)[>]{0,1}[ ]{0,}(?:\r?\n(?:(?!<).)*?){1,}[ ]{0,}{{[('|")]{0,1}(.*?)[('|")]{0,1}[ ]{0,}[|]{1}[ ]{0,}transloco[ ]{0,}}}[ ]{0,}(?:\r?\n.*?)([<]{1}[\/]{1}(?P=tag))
```

and testing data

```
<div>   
  <span>
    {{ 'setup.steps.accountInfo' | transloco }}
  </span>
  <span>
    {{ 'setup.steps.accountInfo' | transloco }}
  </span>
<button
  mat-icon-button
  class="setup__back-btn"
  [ngClass]="{ 'setup__back-btn--visible':                     activePane === 'right' }"
  (click)="onPaneToggleClicked('left')">
    {{ 'setup.steps.accountInfo' | transloco }}
</button>
```

and I want to get results of matching groups "tag" and "name" in bash script.

But I found only this solution so far

```
text="
<div>   
  <span>
    {{ 'setup.steps.accountInfo' | transloco }}
  </span>
  <span>
    {{ 'setup.steps.accountInfo' | transloco }}
  </span>
<button
  mat-icon-button
  class=\"setup__back-btn\"
  [ngClass]=\"{ 'setup__back-btn--visible':                     activePane === 'right' }\"
  (click)=\"onPaneToggleClicked('left')\">
    {{ 'setup.steps.accountInfo' | transloco }}
</button>
"
TRANSLOCO_MULTILINE_PATTERN="(?m)^[ ]{0,}<(?<tag>.*?)[ ]{0,}(?:\r?\n(?:(?!<).)*?){1,}[ ]{0,}{{[('|\")]{0,1}(?<name>.*?)[('|\")]{0,1}[ ]{0,}[|]{1}[ ]{0,}transloco[ ]{0,}}}[ ]{0,}(?:\r?\n.*?)[<]{1}[\/]{1}(?P=tag)"

matches=();
while read match
do
    matches+=( "$match" );
done< <( echo "$text"| grep -Pzo "$TRANSLOCO_MULTILINE_PATTERN")

for (( i = 0; i < ${#matches[@]}; i++ ));
do
    matchRaw="${matches[$i]}";
    match="${matchRaw#*\:}";
    printf 'Match %s, "%s"\n' "$((i + 1))" "$match";
done
```

which returns unusable results for my scenario
output:

```
Match 1, "<span>"
Match 2, "{{ 'setup.steps.accountInfo' | transloco }}"
Match 3, "</span>      <span>"
Match 4, "{{ 'setup.steps.accountInfo' | transloco }}"
Match 5, "</span>    <button"
Match 6, "mat-icon-button"
Match 7, "class="setup__back-btn""
Match 8, " activePane === 'right' }""
Match 9, "(click)="onPaneToggleClicked('left')">"
Match 10, "{{ 'setup.steps.accountInfo' | transloco }}"
```

but I want to get exact results of groups.. and in the best scenario with line number of match

Desired output is groups of match

```
match 1
group tag  12-16    span
group name 24-49    'setup.steps.accountInfo

match 2
group tag  79-83    span
group name 91-116   'setup.steps.accountInfo
```

Using bash version: 4.4.23

Comment: How does your desired output for your example script look like? You could perhaps add that at the bottom of you question. Also, I get `bash: !: event not found` when running the line with setting TRANSLOCO_MULTILINE_PATTERN in bash version 5.0.17.

Comment: Some tips for cleaning up your regex: `{1,}` can be replaced with `+`, `{0,}` can be replaced with `*` and `{0,1}` can be replaced with `?`

Comment: I am afraid it can only be done in a language like Perl, there are too many issues to handle when writing this solution for Bash including multiple matching, dot behavior, line break coding inside the pattern, let alone trying to keep track of line numbers.